# How can l get HOG descriptors on superpixels

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, image-segmentation, scikit-image, superpixels

l would like to get HOG descriptors on superpixels.

**What l have tried ?**

```
image=dim(224,224)
```

## compute hog on the image

```
from skimage.feature import hog
1D_hog,hog_image = hog(rgb2gray(image), orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16), cells_per_block=(1, 1))

hog_image=dim(14,14,1,1,8)
1D_hog=dim(14*14*8)
```

## image segmentation with slic superpixels

```
from skimage.segmentation import slic
segments_slic = slic(image, n_segments=150, compactness=0.01, sigma=1)

segment_slic=dim(224,224)
```

**What l need to get ?**

given `segment_slic` and `hog_image`  how can l get HOG  descriptors of each superpixel ?

**Expected output :**

```
superpixels_descriptors=hog_superpixels(segments_slic,hog_image)
superpixels_descriptors=dim(100,8)
```

where 100 is the number of superpixels and 8 is the orientations (bin histogram of HOG)